# Finding the inverse of an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, inverse, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I'm looking for a computational approach here, since I don't think there is a closed-form solution.

I have the following:

$$ s(x) = \rho + \int_{\rho}^{x} \sqrt{ 1 + (\alpha \cos t - k)^2 } \, dt $$

$ k = \frac{\rho \sin \alpha - \alpha \sin(\rho \cos \alpha)}{\frac{\pi}{2} - \rho \cos \alpha} $ for $x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, otherwise $k=0$.

The following are all constants: $0 < \rho < \frac{\pi}{2}$, $0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$ (and thus $k$).

I'd like to find $x$ such that $s(x) = r$ for some constant $0 \le r \le \pi$.

The interesting thing is that $s(x)$ is an elliptic integral for $x \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$, because $k=0$.  However, my lower limit $\rho$ means that I need to handle $k \ne 0$.

My hunch is that I can use some kind of series expansion here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerical approach I would use here is quite obvious: reducing the problem to an ODE. From the integral itself it's clear that:

$$\frac{ds}{dx} = \sqrt{ 1 + (\alpha \cos x - k)^2 }$$

$$s(\rho)=\rho$$

Now we simply invert the function:

> $$\frac{dx}{ds} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 + (\alpha \cos x - k)^2 }}$$
>
> $$x(\rho)=\rho$$

Now we use any suitable numerical scheme, for example, the simplest explicit Euler method.

$$x_0=\rho$$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{\Delta s}{\sqrt{ 1 + (\alpha \cos x_n - k)^2 }}$$

To reach $r$ we take:

$$\Delta s=\frac{r-\rho}{N}$$

Then:

$$x_{N} \approx x(r)$$